# mv: cannot stat with *

Tags: files

I've tried this before. I swear I was able to issue this kind of command before:

```
mv /home/user/temp1/* /home/user/temp2
```

Basically, I got this command from here: https://superuser.com/questions/273254/move-files-and-folders-recursively-in-linux

Any idea why it's telling me

```
mv: cannot stat `/home/user/temp1/*': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 8):

I can think of 2 possible reasons why this can happen:

1. The source directory may not exist
   (OR)
2. The source directory might be empty

Ignore if neither!

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `$USER` for user to expand to your username. `/home/user` is only valid if you have a user named `user`. This will work if `temp1` and `temp2` exists in your home directory

```
mv /home/$USER/temp1/* /home/$USER/temp2
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to help out and clear up the confusion a little:

- If you want to move a folder **and** its contents to another one, you enter:

  `mv ~/Scripts ~/Podcasts`
- If you want to move a folder's contents but **not** the folder itself to another folder, you must enter, for example, `mv ~/Scripts/* ~/Podcasts`. You can enter `echo ~/Scripts/*` to check the folder's content
- (If you also need to know about `globstar`, which will allow you to recurse through all directory levels, see [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690809/bash-what-expands-to-all-files-in-current-directory-recursively). It can be enabled with shopt -s globstar, but that will need to be put in .bashrc to work permanently.)

(The `tilde` ~ in ~/Scripts is expanded to `/home/mike/` or your user name automatically by the shell)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash and the source directory is empty, you can modify the shell's default glob expansion behavior with:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

to enable the nullglob and cause any succeeding commands like `mv` to behave properly when the source directory is empty. Beware that this can cause other commands such as `ls` to behave unexpectedly.

You can disable the nullglob again with:

```
shopt -u nullglob
```

For more information, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729784/mv-cannot-stat-error-no-such-file-or-directory-error) and [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob).