# mv: cannot stat 'pencil.desktop': No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I have been trying to install the [Pencil Project](https://pencil.evolus.vn/Downloads.html) on Ubuntu-18.04 to design user interfaces before implementing it. 
I have been having the following installation problem and I am not sure why. After downloading it I only

```
sudo apt install ./pencil_3.1.0.ga_amd64.deb && sudo apt install -f
```

Below the warning:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i pencil_3.1.0.ga_amd64.deb && sudo apt install -f 
(Reading database ... 257381 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to unpack pencil_3.1.0.ga_amd64.deb ... 
Unpacking pencil (3.1.0.ga) over (3.1.0.ga) ... 
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/applications/pencil.desktop': No such file or directory 
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/applications/pencil.png': No such file or directory 
Setting up pencil (3.1.0.ga) ... 
mv: cannot stat 'pencil.desktop': No such file or directory 
mv: cannot stat 'pencil.png': No such file or directory 
chmod: cannot access '/usr/share/applications/pencil.*': No such file or directory 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 529 not upgraded.
```

And I am not sure why is not being installed.
I consulted [this source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77007/mv-cannot-stat-no-such-file-or-directory-in-shell-script) and also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164497/mv-cannot-stat-with) and both sources said that there is a missing file in the folder indicated in the warning. There seems to be a missing icon or `.png`. But I downloaded the `.deb` from the [official documentation](https://pencil.evolus.vn/Downloads.html). and simply

```
sudo apt install ./pencil_3.1.0.ga_amd64.deb && sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error. On a side note, `529 not upgraded` doesn't look good.

Comment: Thanks for reading the question. Do you think I should upgrade? Also I can't explain myself `mv: cannot stat 'pencil.desktop': No such file or directory` and `chmod: cannot access '/usr/share/applications/pencil.*': No such file or directory `

Comment: What does that mean? Installation should be straightforward but...

Comment: Uninstall (the corrupt package?) with `$ sudo apt remove pencil` and install this: `$ sudo dpkg -i pencil_3.1.0.20200319003004_amd64.deb` https://pencil.evolus.vn/Nightly.html → Start the app `$ /opt/pencil-3.1.0.20200319003004/pencil` ... and the "pencil GUI" opens.

Comment: P.S. : The errors happens with both packages, when you do a repeated install of the same version.

Comment: Perfect that works with the `.deb` given!! :) Thank you. I could not remove the old version [see here](https://i.imgur.com/QW90z4z.png). I still see the strange warning of the `529 not upgraded`. I did `sudo apt upgrade` correctly though. If you would like to write the answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> rm: cannot remove /usr/share/applications/pencil.desktop: No such file .. rm: cannot remove
>   /usr/share/applications/pencil.png: No such file

Pencil errors : The packages are packed "as wrong as possible" with scripts {postinst, postrm} containing install / remove text from the RPM package. But the text doesn't match the installed files ! Attempts to remove non installed files.

I installed the package 'pencil_3.1.0.ga' with `gdebi` to get the dependencies installed too. But `/opt/pencil-3.1.0.ga/` was empty. Removing was done with `sudo apt remove pencil` and  succeeded.

Install solution https://pencil.evolus.vn/dl/development/pencil_3.1.0.20200319003004_amd64.deb

```
$ sudo dpkg -i pencil_3.1.0.20200319003004_amd64.deb

$ /opt/pencil-3.1.0.20200319003004/pencil
        ## the pencil GUI opens
```

... The launcher 'pencil.desktop' is in `/opt/pencil-3.1.0.20200319003004/`, and can be copied to `/usr/share/applications/`